# Persist complex array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am having a hard time understating what I need to do in order to persist a complex array I have. The array is filled through an ajax call to a jsonresult and has a couple of strings and 2 objects, something like this:

```
{

  Name

  Age

  Surname

  Object 1

  Object 2

}
```

This array is filled whenever I load my "main page". Now when I change page to lets say page B I would like to still have access to those values.
I know that its possible to use json stringify but I would like to maintain the array without needing to convert it to a string, because I would need to convert the numbers back to numbers.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are generally three options, local storage, cookies or storing it on the serverside. There is no persistence in HTML or javascript in a browser when a page reloads

Comment: JSON can represent numbers just fine.

Comment: @adeneo so which one is best suited if I have to reload the array 2 in 2mins?

Comment: @adeneo local storage sounds good to me, what's missing is a link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and the pro tip that it's limited to 5MB.

Comment: IndexedDB is also a thing. Browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is `Now when I change page to lets say page B I would like to still have access to those values.`

The Javascript scope (that is, all the variables and functions you want to use) only lives as long as the page does. So, if you refresh, it kills the scope (all your variables will disappear)!

So, how to persist your information? As the commenters have said, you've got some options.

- Traditionally, cookies are used - there's a lot of tutorials on how to do that. They store a key, a value, and an expiration.
- HTML5 API has introduced browser storage, which is generally better than cookies, but less widely supported (although it's pretty good now in 2015).
- You can store it on the server using a server-side language like PHP, Ruby, Java, etc. and pass it back to the page when the page is rendered.

Basically, Javascript cannot store variables by itself if the page is refreshed.  You've got to use one of the above options, which are each an interesting learning curve by themselves (outside the scope of this question).

I'd recommend, in order:

1. starting with session storage if you're just experimenting
2. cookies if you want to build a resilient solution
3. server-side stuff if you want to take the red pill.

---

Incidentally, your notation is not correct for Javascript - arrays are notated using

```
["foo", "bar", "etc"]
```

and Javascript objects (which can be used as associative arrays) look like

```
{ "key": "value", "ghandi": "india", "mandela", "south africa" }
```